# Run a mi proyecto

Tags: java, apache, eclipse, tomcat

Buen día , estoy tratando de hacer correr mi proyecto en eclipse, y me sale un error, que el servidor no se pudo iniciar en localhost

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me salia error de puertos he cambiado los puertos, he vuelto agregar servidor y nose que pasa, me podrían ayudar a resolverlo porfavor.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow. ¿Sabes que en Internet escribir en mayúsculas se considera gritar?

Comment: no sabía, lo siento

Comment: Deberías buscar el log del servidor y ver qué pone... presumiblemente, en algún punto te debería salir una excepción explicando qué ha fallado.

Comment: lo configure y ahora , sale un error de informe de estado, que mi proyecto no está disponible, ¿que significa?

Comment: Intenta [esto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13244233/server-tomcat-v7-0-server-at-localhost-failed-to-start-without-stack-trace-whi) y nos dejas saber si te funciona.

Comment: Si intentas iniciar el servidor solo, tampoco funciona ? o únicamente es al tratar de iniciarlo con el proyecto ? Si ya tienes el log, puedes subirlo para ver qué pasa.